# Intel Core i3 10100 graphic driver in Windows Server 2016

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, windows-server-2016

The original driver is not compatible with Windows Server 2016.

How to fix this?

Comment: If it is not compatible with your OS then you may have to upgrade to an OS that it is compatible with.

Comment: Windows Server 2016 is concurrent to Windows 10. [These drivers](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/199283/intel-core-i310100-processor-6m-cache-up-to-4-30-ghz/downloads.html) are compatible. Where did you get your driver?

Comment: The drivers you introduced were not compatible.
I had to change my windows to 2019